# How to determine the date an app is installed or used for the first time?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I'm planning on opening up an in app store and I'd like to give existing users some of the items for free.

I thought of releasing an update which would store some informaion the first time the app is used, then release the "real" update that'd look if the app was purchased before, however, it's likely that not everyone will opt for the first update.

So, is there a way to find out when exactly a user has first installed <strike>(or used)</strike> the app ?

**Update :**

Thanks for the answers, but I should make the it less ambiguous :

I'm looking for a native call/anything similar to do it. Since the app is already on store and I haven't set up anything to store the data on the first version, an update will help me do what I want if **all the users** grab it before the second update is released : It'd be impossible to distinguish a new user from an existing one who had missed the intermediary update and has just updated to the most recent one.

Comment: How did you solve this? How did checking the last modified date work out?

Comment: It seems it hadn't worked out because of some other bug in my program, it has just worked fine now. I don't know what would happen if the user deletes the app then restores it back in the future, but I couldn't find a better way.

Comment: Did you check out @medTechy answer, I think checking user app documents directory creation date seem like the right solution!?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's been a long time since I last needed it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My solution would be to check the last modified date of one of the files in the app bundle.

```
NSString *sourceFile = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Icon.png"];

NSDate *lastModif = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:sourceFile error:&err] objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
```

Comment: Seems like you should check the creation date seeing as you may update the Icon and then submit a new build and not think about this check.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work if you have to do this with an update as it will display the new date after the update :(

Comment: Anyone got a clue how to do this on Android?

Comment: @MadhavaJay You could query the package manager for the same

getPackageManager()
    .getPackageInfo("package.name", 0)
    .firstInstallTime

Comment: How this can be an approved solution? It is wrong with common sense. If a person buy a new phone or delete the app, local info is not available to check at all.

Answer (score 50):

To get the installation date, check the creation date of the Documents folder.

```
NSURL* urlToDocumentsFolder = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
__autoreleasing NSError *error;
NSDate *installDate = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:urlToDocumentsFolder.path error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileCreationDate];

NSLog(@"This app was installed by the user on %@", installDate);
```

To get the date of the last App update, check the modification date of the App bundle itself

```
NSString* pathToInfoPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Info" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString* pathToAppBundle = [pathToInfoPlist stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSDate *updateDate  = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:pathToAppBundle error:&error] objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];

NSLog(@"This app was updated by the user on %@", updateDate);
```

Comment: That's seem like the right solution, any body know why this could not work?

Comment: Slight typo in this, pathToDocumentsFolder should be an NSURL object. You would then use the .path accessor when referencing it in the attributesOfItemAtPath method. Otherwise this seems to work great.

Comment: Will this work across iOS version updates? For example, iOS7 -> iOS 8 moves apps to a different directory.

Comment: I verified that installDate doesn't change when updating from 8.1 to 8.3. iOS 7 -> iOS 8 is still an open question.

Comment: For the benefit of the community I am moving an answer that was posted by [Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5168004/boris) which should have been a comment. Due to rep they can't but it was aimed at this answer; _Since I cannot comment as I don't yet have enough rep, Drew H's answer works well up to ios version 10.2 where it breaks - the modified date of the app bundle returns 0 (01/01/1970)_

Answer (score 13):

```
NSDate *installDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"installDate"];

if (!installDate) {
    //no date is present
    //this app has not run before
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:todaysDate forKey:@"installDate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

    //nothing more to do?
} else {
    //date is found
    NSDate *todaysDate = [NSDate date];
    //compare todaysDate with installDate
    //if enough time has passed, yada yada,
    //apply updates, etc.
}
```

Comment: Sweet solve, Justin! Stumbled onto it from Google and it was exactly what I was looking for. :)

Comment: The problem with this is, the user may not run the app on the same date it was installed.
For eg., technically, he could install the app in January and run it in March, in which case the `NSUserDefault` key would store the wrong date (March).

Comment: True, but semantically speaking we could just change the installDate bool to "firstRun". There's no way to know the absolute install date. Except the guy below me says the create date of the docs directory is true for install. Neat

Answer (score 8):

Using the creation date of Documents directory is the best solution so far. Reproducing it in Swift 5.0

```
var inferredDateInstalledOn: Date? {
    guard
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last,
        let attributes = try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: documentsURL.path)
    else { return nil }
    return attributes[.creationDate] as? Date
}
```

Answer (score 3):

App build date:

```
public var appBuildDate: Date {
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") {
    if let createdDate = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: path)[.creationDate] as? Date {
      return createdDate
    }
  }
  return Date() // Should never execute
}
```

App installation date:

```
public var appInstallDate: Date {
  if let documentsFolder = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last {
    if let installDate = try! FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: documentsFolder.path)[.creationDate] as? Date {
      return installDate
    }
  }
  return Date() // Should never execute
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 16 you can get information about the original purchase using a new API

```
let result: VerificationResult<AppTransaction> = try await AppTransaction.shared
   switch result {
      case .unverified:
         break
 
      case .verified(let signedType):
         let dateFirstInstalled = signedType.originalPurchaseDate
}
```

signed type also included the original purchase version string, should you need it.

Comment: Does this also work when the app is uninstalled and reinstalls again? I mean would this give the very first installation date disregarding all the reinstalls?

Comment: @Mark Bridges: Yes :) `The original purchase date remains the same, even if the user deletes and reinstalls the app.`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction/3954448-originalpurchasedate

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little safer approach, with out the force try and force unwrapping, and update to suit **SWIFT 5**:

```
if
    let urlToDocumentsFolder = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).last,
    let installDateAny = (try? FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: urlToDocumentsFolder.path)[.creationDate]),
    let installDate = installDateAny as? Date
{
    print("This app was installed by the user on \(installDate)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend simply setting a date on first launch and storing it in NSUserDefaults. Look for the date on launch, if it's not there, set it. If it is, do some date comparison and handle the rest according to your plan.

Answer (score 1):

Answering to see if people can find fault in this. It seemed longer than the others I find here, but it does tell you if app is running for the first time since updating (for this you have to change your info.plist)...

```
// called during startup, compares the current version string with the one stored on standardUserDefaults
+ (BOOL)isFreshInstallOrUpdate
{
    BOOL ret = YES;
    NSString *cfBundleVersionStored = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    NSString *cfBundleShortVersionStringStored = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    NSString *cfBundleVersionPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];;
    NSString *cfBundleShortVersionStringPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:
                                                 @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    ret = [cfBundleVersionPlist compare:cfBundleVersionStored] != NSOrderedSame ||
    [cfBundleShortVersionStringPlist compare:cfBundleShortVersionStringStored] != NSOrderedSame;

    return ret;
}


// calling this once will necessarily cause isFreshInstall to return false
+ (void)setStoredVersionNumber
{
    NSString *cfBundleVersionPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    NSString *cfBundleShortVersionStringPlist = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:
                                                 @"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cfBundleVersionPlist forKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:cfBundleShortVersionStringPlist forKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"];

    // setting now as unfresh!
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check on the server. It used to be simple with UDID but since these are deprecated you have create a UUID (CFUUIDCreate() or something like that :)) and store it in the keychain, every information stored in the keychain will stay persistent even if user will delete the app and installs again after a year or so ... I found this articke really helpful when handling the keychain values for the first time:
http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/3/29/simple-iphone-keychain-access.html

Answer (score 0):

Swift solution:

```
let urlToDocumentsFolder = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last!
//installDate is NSDate of install
let installDate = (try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(urlToDocumentsFolder.path!)[NSFileCreationDate])
print("This app was installed by the user on \(installDate)")
```