# Is it possible to check when user downloaded my ios app?

Tags: ios, if-statement, nsdate

Is it possible to check when the user downloaded my iOs app, and if so, is it possible to make a if statement out of it like:

```
  if(downloadDate>1march) {

        }
```

sorry if you think the question is bad... any code would be greately appreciated though :D

should also probably mention that my app has been on the AppStore for six months...

Comment: It would help if you explained why you need to do this.

Comment: Well, I have an app that has been paid, but now I want it to be free with ads. But I want to make it so that if you have purchased the app before it got free (specific date), you would not have ads. @rmaddy

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390810/change-paid-app-to-free-but-know-if-user-previously-purchased-it

Comment: Is there (by rare chance) a file that you created once on install and have not modified since?  If so you could query the date on the file.

Comment: Also, there is probably a way to figure out that the app was already installed when you load the new version.  You could set an NSUserDefaults value "AlreadyInstalled" TRUE/FALSE when you load the new version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there's a way to automatically check a download date.

But you can certainly set a date for when the app was very first launched.  In your appDidFinishLaunching method in your app delegate:

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] objectForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
}
```

Any point after this, you can check this date and compare it to whatever you want.

Comment: The problem is that the app has been on the AppStore for 6 months...

Comment: Good point here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090512/how-to-determine-the-date-an-app-is-installed-or-used-for-the-first-time

Comment: Given the OP's comment below the question, this answer doesn't appear to be relevant.

Comment: It looks like the answer from medTechy is good for you.