# How to see if user has downloaded iOs app before?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

How can I can check if the user has downloaded my app before a specific date? I have this code in the viewDidLoad:

```
    if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"FirstLaunch"]){
}
else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:YES forKey:@"FirstLaunch"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
}
```

I there any way for my to use that NSUserDefaults and make a method like :

`If(Firstlaunch>today){
remove iAd
}`

any code would be greatly appreciated! sorry if the question is dumb..

Comment: Why are you repeating your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22108302/is-it-possible-to-check-when-user-downloaded-my-ios-app

Comment: Check the `Original Purchase Date` on the purchase receipt (there are other questions about this on StackOverflow:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943183/a-complete-solution-to-locally-validate-an-in-app-receipts-and-bundle-receipts-o). Link to documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ReceiptFields.html

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1.** Ship the app with a hardcoded date value you would compare with on app's first launch.

**Option 2.** Implement a web service and send a call on app's first launch. The web service would check if the date of performing a request is in a desired range and return this information to you in a response.