# iOS/Swift: how to get app installation time?

Tags: ios, swift

Is there any way to get the app installation time on iOS?

On Android it is available as the `firstInstallTime` property of the `PackageInfo` object

Comment: iOS doesn't provide such information so you'll have to track it by yourself. E.g. by simply storing the date the user first launched your app.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14802309/730701) might be helpful to you.

Comment: Keep in mind if you store the date on your device that it will be lost if the user deletes and re-installs the app later. This may or may not be an issue depending on what you are trying to accomplish. The only thing that persists beyond that is information stored in the KeyChain and that is only lost if the user resets the device to factory settings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine the date an app is installed or used for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090512/how-to-determine-the-date-an-app-is-installed-or-used-for-the-first-time)