# Get date of when app was installed (iOS)

Tags: ios

I was wondering if it was possible to get the installation date of the application.  I am well aware you can store to NSUserDefaults when the app is first loaded, but I am looking for installation date, if possible.

Cheers

Comment: Im well aware it is a duplicate, took awhile to find that source, but posted an answer in Swift below.  The other alternative is to delete this posting but I want this to be a resource to future SO users.

Comment: A post can be closed and not deleted to act as a signpost.  Please review the Help Center article on duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates

Comment: Thank you JAL for the advice.

Answer (score 6):

Found it through this link: [How to determine the date an app is installed or used for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090512/how-to-determine-the-date-an-app-is-installed-or-used-for-the-first-time)

Im using Swift so here is the translation:

```
    let urlToDocumentsFolder = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).last!
    //installDate is NSDate of install
    let installDate = (try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().attributesOfItemAtPath(urlToDocumentsFolder.path!)[NSFileCreationDate])
    print("This app was installed by the user on \(installDate)")
```

Comment: Please close your question as a duplicate rather than copying and pasting answers from other Stack Overflow posts.