# Detect first time app download on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I already have a application on App Store and business team needs to detect the users who's downloading and using the app for the very first time.

Challenge is there's no login for the app and customers can purchase tickets. We need to give a promotion only for the customers who downloaded after some future specific date. (ex : customers who will download for first time after 1st January 2018)

Even if the customer is deleting the app and then re install from apple store, it should not be eligible for the offer.

we can do some code fix and update. But that code will not be affected until they update and launch.

**Note:  It should be first time download only (i.e. they have never had the iOS app on their phone)**

Comment: Did you tried using Keychain? Keychain only reset when user reset iPhone. You can write a flag to keychain to check user install your app in the first time or not

Comment: we can add the code. But what about the existing users? That check will return true even for existing customers who have updated.

Comment: really? if flagKeychain == nil { write flagKeychain and give user a promotion } else { return }

Comment: Think about existing users. They will update the new version along with your logic. Even for them it will be considered as a new customer. Thats my issue

Comment: After you wrote a value to keychain, `flagKeychain == nil` always return false for existing users

Comment: What ever solutioning we do, it should work with the existing customer base also. Imagine a customer is using the existing version. We have to do this code change and deploy a new version. Once customer is updating keychain will be nil and considered as first time user. (which is not the case)

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090512/how-to-determine-the-date-an-app-is-installed-or-used-for-the-first-time.

Comment: Never tried it, but you could try retrieving the app purchase receipt (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1407276-appstorereceipturl) and parse it to retrieve the original application version or maybe the receipt creation date. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Introduction.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my knowledge, There is no way for us to know whether a user has reinstalled user or not until unless we do have our own custom logic like sending emailId or storing in Keychain.

In your case, you have not done any of these things for the app which is already live in the app store. you can not track the reinstalled users. Please find the below segregation of users.

**1. Reinstalled Users:** right now not possible to track these users.

**2. Installed Users (v1.0) & New Users.(V1.1)**
   check this solution [How to determine the date an app is installed or used for the first time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090512/how-to-determine-the-date-an-app-is-installed-or-used-for-the-first-time) to get the timestamp of the document file.

a. If it is less then new app release, then it should be an older version.

b. If it is equal or greater than the new app release timestamp, then it is the new version.

write the keychain logic in the new version so that from now onwards you can use keychain to identify the users.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CFUUID` to create `UUID`, then save it in the keychain. So whenever the app launches, if no `UUID` is found in keychain, it can be said that app is installed for the first time. If `UUID` is found in keychain, it can be said that app has been installed previously. Have a look at below links:

[iOS UDID replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iOS%20UDID%20replacement)

[UDID equivalent](http://Persistent%20UDID%20equivalent%20for%20iOS%207?)

[iOS unique user identifier](http://%20%20iOS%20unique%20user%20identifier)

Comment: Think about existing users. They will update the new version along with your logic. Even for them it will be considered as a new customer. Thats my issue

Comment: What other data are you collecting from user? Are you monitoring app version?

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we were keeping some local sqlite database in the documents folder. So if the file doesn't exist at the time of launch we can assume its a fresh launch. Otherwise its an update.