# Ionic how to check the app is installed for the first time

Tags: capacitor

I am using Capacitor to build ios app, I am looking for a way to detect whether this app is installed for the first time (not deleted and re-installed again).

I didn't find any relevant capacitor/cordova plugin for this. Any advice would appreciate.

Reason why I am asking:
I want to implement a feature for in-app-purchase, where some "special discount" is only applied for the users who downloaded this app for the first time.

Comment: i think localStorage is outdated for this solution. The localStorage will also be cleared along with the app uninstallation

Comment: This is not an ionic / capacitor problem but a mobile development general question. If you've reached this stage in your learning process, then you should ask your self how to create a persistence storage on a mobile application.

Comment: @mahen23 You're right, but there are some techniques to accomplishing what Elias is asking that are specific to his toolset.

Comment: Thanks everyone, one of my friend told me I need to get the user's device uuid and save it in backend database, and check this uuid when user install the app. I will try this out later down in the development path. But would really welcome any other ideas! Thanks

Comment: also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937054/detect-first-time-app-download-on-ios

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.